# Connect external databases in airflow deployed in Kubernetes

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, sqlalchemy, airflow, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to connect my external PostgreSQL database in airflow deployed in Kubernetes using this chart: https://github.com/apache/airflow/tree/master/chart

I am  modifying the values.yml file:

```yml
# Airflow database config
data:
  # If secret names are provided, use those secrets
  metadataSecretName: ~
  resultBackendSecretName: ~

  # Otherwise pass connection values in
  metadataConnection:
    user: <USERNAME>
    pass: <PASSWORD>
    host: <POSTGRESERVER>
    port: 5432
    db: airflow
    sslmode: require
  resultBackendConnection:
    user: <USERNAME>
    pass: <PASSWORD>
    host: <POSTGRESERVER>
    port: 5432
    db: airflow
    sslmode: require
```

But is not working, all my pods are in status: Waiting: PodInitializing.

My PostgreSQL is hosted in Azure Database for PostgreSQL servers and I am afraid that the IP Pods are not allowed in the firewall rules in Azure Database for PostgreSQL.

How can I know what IP my Kubernetes PODS are using to connect to the database?

Comment: you have asked same question twice https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64294633/connect-external-database-in-airflow-deployed-in-kubernetes

Comment: There is no such way to have a long-term static IP on a Pod, it will keep change whenever the pod gets relaunched. So there is no point in adding the IP to your firewall. However, if your DB is publicly accessible you can use the `ExternalName` service to point the DB. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname